# Duplicate fields on signing interface

Tags: docusignapi

I am building up an envelope using multiple templates through the API using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates.

Sometimes the server side templates used to build the envelope contain the same logical fields
e.g. two templates used, both have fields of "Account Number"

How do I make it so when the signer enters data in one account number field, it updates the other account number field with the same data immediately in the signing interface?

It is required to prevent the signer from typing one account number on one document then a different account number on the other document in the same template.

The business logic for the document requires this so removing the duplicate account number fields would not be an option either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an account-level setting that you can configure in DocuSign to force this behavior (i.e., ensure that like-named fields throughout all Documents in an Envelope always contain the same values).  Simply login to the DocuSign web console (as a user with Administrator rights), navigate to "**Preferences** >> **Features**" and on the **Features** page, set **Data Population Scope** to "**Envelope**".  (See page 27 of the DocuSign Admin guide: http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Account%20Administration%20Reference%20Guide.pdf)

Because this is controlled via DocuSign account-level setting, there's nothing special you need to do in your **CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates** API call -- just configure the account setting and you should be good to go.